# MpChart - Icon upon last plotted point

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

is there a way to put an icon over the last plotted point within the chart?

I'd need to obtain something like this:

[image]

Should I use the MarkerView and force the highlighting of the desired point?

Thanks in advance, bye!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [custom markerview class](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView) and add your icon to the background of the textview. Worked for me :)

Comment: Yeah. I came to a solution that uses the mpchart markerView. I keep the icon aligned with the last plotted point highlighting it every time.